# Adding an array to the DOM with each element as an li

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to add this array to the DOM, with each string element as part of an unordered list. Below I try to set message[i] = the element of the array I want to append to the list, but it doesn't appear to be working. Fetch new is an callback function that gets an array of strings as it's input FYI. Basically I am trying to display each element in that array at the bottom of the ul. ul class="messages" fyi. Is there something wrong with the way I am assigning the variable value?

```
   function fetchNew() {
        var PrintChat = function (Chat_Messages) {
        var y = Chat_Messages.length;
        for (i = 0; i < y; i++) {

            var message[i] = $('<li>Chat_Messages[i]<li>');
            $('.messages').append(message[i]);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's literally outputting `Chat_Messages[i]` repeatedly?

You kind of have to tell JavaScript that it's a variable to be concatenated. Try this:

```
$(".messages").append("<li>"+Chat_Messages[i]+"</li>");
```

Note that for safety reasons you should ensure that the message is properly escaped, or better yet use native DOM methods like `createTextNode(Chat_Messages[i])` to protect your site from XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

if fetchNew is a callback that gets an array of string, you're actually complicating it too much, a simpler method would be like so:

```
function fetchNew(myArray) {                           // receive the array as a parameter.
    var length = myArray.length;                       // Cache the length of array
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {                     // loop through the array.
        var element = $('<li>' + myArray[i] + '<li>'); // concatenate the current value inside an LI and create a dom element.
        $('.messages').append(element);                // Add element to the parent container
    }
}
```